# Eclipse Won't Export my Android app

Tags: android, eclipse

I recently changed my computer and now I am trying to export my Android app through Eclipse, but at the last phase in exporting, I get this message:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS4En.png]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a straightforward path error to me. Make sure the path really exists in your computer.

Comment: It should be "C:\Users\Aubtin\workspace\SalesTaxApp\SalesTaxApp" and on my old computer, the IT tech spelled my name wrong. Now, this is happening. I am not sure how to change it so it works on my new computer.